# Every page's styles are loaded on homepage after upgrading to Nuxt 2

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js, nuxt-edge

After upgrading to Nuxt.js 2, I noticed that about 30 CSS files are loaded when the homepage loads. I actually noticed it when I checked Google Pagespeed Insights and saw about 30 "blocking CSS resources".

Is there any setting for lazy loading them or something like that?

Comment: try extractCss: true

Answer (score 0):

Nuxt2 has the code splitting and you can use the every css files in the current page only so you have 2 way for bundling css, first is the common css in the all project and second is an isolate css file for each page. use the `scoped` attribute in the `style` tag.

for example:

```
  //////// sample.vue//////
 <template>
           write somethin.....
 </template>

 <script>
           write som,ething.....
  </script>

  <style lang="scss" scoped>
    body {
          background-color: gray;
          color: #9e9e9e;
      }
  </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
export default {
  build: {
    extractCSS: true,
    optimization: {
      splitChunks: {
        cacheGroups: {
          styles: {
            name: 'styles',
            test: /\.(css)$/,
            chunks: 'all',
            enforce: true
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/3166#issuecomment-423832425

Comment: That doesn't seem to have any effect. No css were merged.

Comment: This might do the opposite of what was requested.